# Using `distinctUntilKeyChanged` or on a bufferTime array

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, observer-pattern

I have this buffer, which every x seconds, will provide a buffer of an array of the last provide values to `this.queue.next()`

```js
    const queue = new Subject()
    const bufferTimeObserver = queue.pipe(
      map((payload) => payload as Task),
      bufferTime(x* 1000),
      filter(data => !!data.length),
      concatMap(
        (taskData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {           
            resolve(taskData)
          }),
      ),
    )

   bufferTimeObserver.subscribe((taskData) => {
     // Do things with data
   })
```

This works a bit like a throttle or debounce, without losing any tasks.

### Example 1

When I get this `taskData`:

```json
[
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 414},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 414},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 415},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 415},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 416}
]
```

I want to apply do `distinctUntilKeyChanged('tabId')` on it, but this doesn't work, because I get an array instead of an object.
(See the first example here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/distinctUntilKeyChanged , can I make an `of` from an incoming array? See bottom attempt at using `from`)

How do I convert this array back into a "normal" observable so I can filter out only the last value? Besides just simply getting the last array item: `items[items.length -1]`, and preferably without changing the original `bufferTimeObserver` composition. (although this might be an option)

So that the result is:

```json
[
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 414},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 415},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 416}
]
```

### Example 2

Given this `taskData`:

```json
[
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 414},
 {type: 'lastWindowFocusId', windowId: 1233},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 415},
 {type: 'lastWindowFocusId', windowId: 11},
 {type: 'lastTabFocusId', tabId: 416}
]
```

Instead of doing a native `filter` on the array:

```js
const focusWindows$ = queue.pipe(
  map((data) => data.filter((item) => item.type === 'lastWindowFocusId')),
  filter(data => !!data.length),
)
```

I'd like to simplify it with the rxjs `filter` like:

```js
const focusWindows$ = queue.pipe(
  filter(data => data.type === 'lastWindowFocusId'),
  filter(data => !!data.length),
)
```

But again, obviously does not work with an array of items.
Here again, what would be the simplest solution to simplify this?

I've tried mapping the array with all sorts of `xMap` operators, but all that does is split the observable into separate ones, and will trigger a 'subscribe' for each branched item.
What I need is to locally convert the array into something that I can operate on like rxjs, but I don't want to have to subscribe to it separately...

For the ultimate solution it would be ideal if I can get the following from the above data:

```json
 {
   tabFocusId: 416,
   windowFocusId: 11
 }
```

So It'd be a combination of plucking, filtering and only using the last distinct values...

### Example 3

Same thing for `pluck('tabId')`, I'd like to do a pluck on each array item, but first it needs to be a stream.

### Attempt x

The following was an attempt at something sembling a solution, yet it is far from it. I must be confusing some ideas:

```js
   bufferTimeObserver.subscribe((taskData) => {
     // Do things with data:
     const task$ = from(taskData)
     task$.subscribe((taskData) => {
       console.log('sub', taskData)
     })
   })
```

This will then trigger a subscribe for each array item, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For **Example 1** I think this could be an approach:

```js
src$.pipe(
  mergeMap(
    taskData =>
      // 'Exploding' the array.
      from(taskData).pipe(
        distinctUntilKeyChanged('tabId'),
        // Collecting the remaining objects in an array.
        toArray()
      ),
  )
)
```

As you intuited, there could be a way to locally operate on the array and `mergeMap` has been used to create that locality. A very important bit is to **recreate the array** after it has been filtered.
The way we do that is by using the `toArray` operator which emits when the source(in this case, `from`) has completed. This is actually the reason `from` has been used: it will **complete** after it has emitted all of the elements of the given array. When an array is given to `from`, the `fromArrayLike` function will be called internally and [here is the part](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/8.x/src/internal/observable/innerFrom.ts#L80) where it indeed sends a **complete notification**:

```js
export function fromArrayLike<T>(array: ArrayLike<T>) {
  return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => {
    /* ... */
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length && !subscriber.closed; i++) {
      subscriber.next(array[i]);
    }
    subscriber.complete();
  });
}
```

The approach can be taken for **Example 2** or **Example 3**:

```js
src$.pipe(
  mergeMap(
    taskData =>
      // 'Exploding' the array.
      from(taskData).pipe(

        // Apply any operators on each individual object.
        filter(/* ... */),
        distinctUntilKeyChanged(/* ... */),

        // Collecting the remaining objects in an array.
        toArray()
      ),
  )
)
```